# macOS Terminal - Always resets to default

Tags: terminal

I read a ticket [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/92756/prevent-mac-terminal-from-reverting-to-default-theme) which is the same as an issue I'm experiencing.

Simply changing the "default" while that Terminal session works while that Terminal instance is still open, but if I quit Terminal and re-open, it comes up as the basic/default again!

How can I fix this ??

Comment: What MacOS version? Please describe exactly the steps you take.

Answer (score 1):

Under the General tab in the Terminal settings, Make sure your desired profile is set in the "On startup, open: New window with profile:"

...and the "New windows open with:" is set to "Default Profile".

[image]